# python's sys.argv seems to split some arguments on dots when invoked from powershell

Tags: python, powershell

It looks like when python is invoked from powershell, later arguments of the form "-foo.bar" are split at the dot and seen by python as two separate arguments.  Is this a bug?  A feature of powershell?  Something else?

powershell:

```
> python -c "import sys; print(sys.argv)" foo.bar -foo.bar
['-c', 'foo.bar', '-foo', '.bar']
```

cmd or linux:

```
> python -c "import sys; print(sys.argv)" foo.bar -foo.bar
['-c', 'foo.bar', '-foo.bar']
```

This also happens when doing e.g. `python -mfoo.bar` which is normally equivalent to `python -m foo.bar`, but, from powershell, becomes `python -mfoo .bar`.

Comment: probably because the parser sees `-string` as a parameter statement and `.` is an invalid char in that, so it splits it into a separate argument.  Quote that string and it'll work: `'-foo.bar'`.  This has to do with powershell's binding semantics.

Comment: A safe way to deal with external calls: use the stop-parser operator which will fall back to whatever the primary is (on Windows, cmd): `python --% ...`

Comment: I guess I was confused because I thought that windows executables only saw a single command line string that was split by commandlinetoargv, but I guess that's something cmd.exe handles but pwsh does differently?